# How to set a Tag to a Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I've looked at all the questions on Stackoverflow but could not find a single definitive answer to this question. How do you **set a Tag to a `Fragment`** so that you can retrieve it via `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag()`? Could someone give a simple code example of how to create a tag to a `Fragment`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set a `Tag` during fragment transaction.

For example if it's a `replace` transaction you could do it like so:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment, TAG)
        .commit();
```

If the `Fragment` you're using is **not** from Support Library, use `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

I used that feature to provide between `Dialog` box and `Fragment`.
When a alteration is made in `Dialogbox`, App can easily update `Fragment` UI

MyFragment.

```
DialogFragment dialog = LastCycleDate.newInstance( last_period_start );
        dialog.setTargetFragment( this, 0 );
        dialog.show( getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "showLastCycleDate" );
```

MyDailogBox.java

```
Fragment targetFragment; = getTargetFragment();
if( targetFragment instanceof IntroParentFragment ){
            IntroParentFragment introParentFragment = ( IntroParentFragment ) targetFragment;
            introParentFragment.mutualMethods.setLastCycleStartDay( start_date );
        }
```