# removing fragment with popBackStack();

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a few fragments in one activity. In Main Activity I implemented `popBackStack();` in `onBackPressed();`

So that, you can always go back to previous fragment clicking back button. *But `popBackStack();` doesn't remove the fragment I just left*.

> How to achieve removing current fragment each time, we click back
>   button?

Comment: How do you load the fragments? Do you call addToBackStack()? If so you don't need to implement onBackPressed() as Android does this for you.

Comment: As told by code-apprentice, if you properly add fragment during fragment transaction. Then you need not pop out the fragment specifically. popbackStack is generally used for buttons and clicks other than back button

Comment: look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025331/how-can-i-control-the-activitys-up-button-from-a-contained-fragment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public void removeFragmentbyTag(String myFrag){

 FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
 trans.remove(myFrag);
 trans.commit();
 manager.popBackStack();
}
```

hope this bit of code help you.

Comment: how do I get a fragment tag in MainActivity with onBackPressed function?

Comment: when you add fragments to main activity add fragment tag to each fragment

Comment: getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentToBeAdded, tag).commit();    where tag is String

Comment: you can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062129/how-to-set-a-tag-to-a-fragment-in-android

Comment: Thanks. You have saved my day.

Comment: You can also use `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentcontainer)).commit();`